# Исключение типа System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, массивы, исключения

Нужно считать массив из любого числа элементов, сами числа могут быть как целыми, так и с запятой. При запуске выходит исключение System.IndexOutOfRangeException в этой строке:

```
arr[i, j] = row[j];
```

Лишних пробелов вроде нет. Ps я начинающий программист

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int size = 4;

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\учеба\КОЭД\data.txt").Take(10).ToArray();

    int[,] arr = new int[size, size];


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int[] row = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            arr[i, j] = row[j];
        }
    }

    // вывести в текстбокс
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            textBox1.Text += arr[i, j].ToString() + "\t";
        }

        textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }

    // посчитать среднее
    MessageBox.Show(arr.Cast<int>().Average().ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В `row` элементов меньше, чем `size`.

Comment: Как это исправить, не подскажите?
У меня в текстовом файле в общем порядка 10 столбцов и 20 строк

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int[] row = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < size && j < row.Length; j++)
    {
        ...
```